# Adding PhysicsImpostor turning meshes upside-down

Tags: typescript, blender, babylonjs

I'm loading a mesh from a GLB file that I've exported from Blender.  The problem I'm having is that as soon as I add the PhysicsImpostor to the meshes - the whole model flips upside down?!?

```
export class Player extends BABYLON.AbstractMesh {
    constructor(scene, config: EntityConfig) {
        super(config.name, scene);

        BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh('', 'assets/', config.file, scene,
            (newMeshes, particleSystems, skeletons, animationGroup) => {
            newMeshes.forEach(m => {
                if (!m.parent)
                    m.setParent(this);

                m.showBoundingBox = config.IS_DEBUG;
                m.physicsImpostor = new BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor(m, BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor.);
        });

        this.scaling.set(.2, .2, .2);

        this.setAbsolutePosition(new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 3, 0));

        scene.registerAfterRender(() => {
            animationGroup[0].play(true);
        });       

        this.physicsImpostor = new BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor(this, BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor.SphereImpostor, 
            {
                mass: 1,
                restitution: .1 
            }, scene);

        this.showBoundingBox = config.IS_DEBUG;
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Here he is upside-down...]

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer that without a playground or a demo. But looking at the code, there might be a few things you can do.

My first guess would be that this will help - you should construct the impostors in order (child first), and try avoiding using the setParent function when loading GLB/GLTF, since they are right-handed and babylon is left handed and when using setParent, the child is getting the parent's transformation applied to it. If you use `m.parent = this` instead, the parent's transformation is taken into account when rendering the object, but its basic transformation is not changing. So the first thing I would do is change `m.setParent(this);` to `m.parent = this`.

You can read about compounds here - https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/compounds

Another suggestion would be to create a mesh impostor for the entire model instead of an impostor per mesh (compound). If you however need the individual meshes to move, a compound (using the parenting system) will anyhow not work and you will need to create individual impostors and connect them using joints (https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/joints).

Also - I don't see what physics engine you decided to use. For complex tasks (especially if you need a `MeshImpostor` Ammo.js would be my first choice.